# Popup when User_From field is left blank in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The following will open a popup if the field is empty, I would like it to popup if any field is left blank when inputting via the MSVB userform named MVR.   I have 4 fields so can I have four separate popups if not filled in?

```
'find first empty row in database
iRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

'check for a MVR number
If Trim(Me.txtMVR.Value) = "" Then
    Me.txtMVR.SetFocus
    MsgBox "Please enter MVR number"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below to your `MSVB` user_form code module (in a `CommandButton1_Click` event, or what you have).

It will loop through all `TextBox`es in your User_Form, and if one of them is left blank it will pop-up the `MsgBox`.

```
Dim TB As MSForms.TextBox

For Each TB In Me.Controls
    If Trim(TB.Value) = "" Then
        TB.SetFocus
        MsgBox "Please enter a value / number"
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next TB
```